# How can I explicitly construct a *nice* conformal mapping from a triangle to a square in MATLAB?

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods

I know the basics of the Riemann mapping theorem, SC maps, etc. I can look up formulae for the maps from the half-plane to a triangle or rectangle. But I want a particularly nice explicit map--easily implementable in MATLAB--from a triangle with horizontal base to a rectangle aligned with the coordinate axes.* In particular, I want each of the sides of the triangle to map exactly to a side of the rectangle, so that it "unfolds".

I have played with the [Schwarz-Christoffel toolbox for MATLAB](http://www.math.udel.edu/~driscoll/SC/index.html) but after some effort have not been able to get the result I want. The closest I've been able to get is using the command sequence

```
L = 128; 
ell = L/sqrt(12);
p1 = polygon([-L/2-i*ell,L/2-i*ell,i*2*ell]);
p2 = polygon(L/2*[-1-i,1-i,1+i,-1+i]);
f1 = stripmap(p1,[1,2])
f2 = stripmap(p2,[1,2])
f1i = inv(f1)
f2i = inv(f2)
fc = composite(f1i,f2)
n = 100;
s = linspace(-L/2,L/2,n);
t = linspace(-ell,2*ell,n);
[x,y] = meshgrid(s,t);
z = x+i*y;
z = z(find(isinpoly(z,p1)));
w = eval(fc,z);
figure;scatter(real(z),imag(z),5,1:length(z),'filled')
figure;scatter(real(w),imag(w),5,1:length(z),'filled')
```

...but this has a bizarre asymmetry that's presumably due to numerics, and (of much less concern) it's some nasty sort of involutionish thing away from how I want it. See below for the graphics. Most other variations I've tried have failed miserably.

[image]
[image]

*For convenience, we can take the triangle to be equilateral, but I really want a right triangle with shortest side aligned with the y-axis and length 1, and the next shortest side aligned with the x-axis and length 2.

Comment: is your asymmetry coming from `t = linspace(-ell,2*ell,n);`? This will give you a uniform vector centered around $\frac12 \textrm{ell}$, not $0$.

Comment: @Arkamis--I don't think so. That's just the y-limits of the equilateral triangle, which is centered at the origin.

Comment: I should also note that I've seen http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/SchwarzChristoffelMod.html and this (or similar maps) doesn't really solve my problem AFAIK.

Comment: Actually, your triangle isn't symmetric about zero. You're going from $-\frac{L}{2}-i\textrm{ell}$ to $+\frac{L}{2}-i\textrm{ell}$. It should be $+ i\textrm{ell}$ in the second argument, if you want it to be equilateral.

Comment: Other than that, the code seems to give you more or less what you want. I don't know enough about the toolbox to help beyond that :/

Comment: @Arkamis--Look at the polygon p1. The stuff you're preoccupied with doesn't have anything to do with the actual polygon, just an easy way to generate points inside it.

Comment: I'm just looking at the asymmetry issue, which as you say is minor, but I am dubious about the source being numerical in nature. In any case, the image of the polygon P1 is clearly not centered with the peak at zero. The peak is close to where the confluence point seems to be in P2.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, magnifying the image does show it to be mostly symmetric. It appears that the re-sized image has some skew on my browser. Weird...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12609/discussion-between-s-huntsman-and-arkamis)

Comment: Unfortunately, I am indisposed at the moment. Perhaps tomorrow.